# Need help optimizing an algorithm that's supposed to maximize the greatest common divisor of n elements by removing at most one element

Tags: algorithms, optimization, number-theory

Alright, first here's the text of the problem:

You're  given n bags of candies where the i-th bag contains a[i] candies and  all numbers a[i] are in the segment [1,m]. You can choose a natural  number x and each second remove x candies from one of the bags if it  contains at least x candies. The goal is to empty all the bags *except at most one of them*. Find the greatest possible value of x that allows you to achieve this goal.

The desired time complexity is O(n* log m);

What I managed(I think) to do is write an O(n^2 * log m) algorithm (the two nested for loops are O(n^2) and Euclid's algorithm is O(log m)).

The code written in c++ is below. The second for loop calculates the gcd of the numbers excluding the i-th number and I calculate the maximum by considering all values of i, but apparently it can be done linearly. 
Any  ideas on how to optimize it to O(n* log m)?

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}


int greatestPossibleGcd(int *arr, int n){
    int maxgcd = 0;
    int current = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        maxgcd = gcd(maxgcd, arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j == i)
                continue;
            current = gcd(current, arr[j]);
        }
        if(current > maxgcd)
            maxgcd = current;

        current = 0;
    }

    return maxgcd;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science, Irrelevant! Hmm, unregistered irrelevance...

Comment: The answer is easy. However, I am concerned whether this problem is a part of live contest.

Comment: Apparently, (fill in your hypothesis ...)